# Nested aggregation and grouping on multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the following `product` table (which is highly trimmed down):

```
`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT
`category_id` int
`subcategory_id` int
`vendor_id` int
`price` decimal(6,2)
`inserted_at` timestamp
```

For a given category ID, I am attempting to retrieve a list containing the vendor with the lowest latest price for each subcategory. With "latest" I mean that vendors may have multiple prices for a given category ID/subcategory ID combination, so only the most recently inserted price for that category ID/subcategory ID/vendor ID should be used. If there's a tie between 2 or more vendor's prices, the lowest id should be used as the tie-breaker.

For example, with this data:

```
id | category_id | subcategory_id | vendor_id | price | inserted_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 2              | 3         | 16.00 | 2015-07-23 04:00:00  
2  | 1           | 1              | 2         |  9.00 | 2015-07-26 08:00:00 
3  | 1           | 2              | 4         | 16.00 | 2015-08-02 10:00:00 
4  | 1           | 1              | 1         |  7.00 | 2015-08-04 11:00:00
5  | 1           | 1              | 1         | 11.00 | 2015-08-09 16:00:00
```

So, first find the most recent prices for every subcategory/vendor combination (row with `price=7.00` would be removed because it's not the most recent for that vendor in that subcategory). Then for subcategory 1 the lowest price would be 9 (so vendor_id = 2) and for subcategory 2 the lowest price is 16 (two vendors tie ()ids 3 and 4) so we choose the one with lowest vendor_id = 3).

I would expect the following results for `category_id = 1`:

```
subcategory_id | vendor_id | price
----------------------------------
1              | 2         |  9.00
2              | 3         | 16.00
```

Here's what I have so far. I feel like it's already starting to get out of hand and this doesn't even account for ties between 2 or more vendor's prices.

```
SELECT c.subcategory_id, c.vendor_id, c.price
FROM products AS c
JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(a.price) AS min_price,
           a.subcategory_id
    FROM products AS a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT  MAX(`inserted_at`) AS latest_price_time,
                vendor_id,
                subcategory_id
        FROM    products
        WHERE   category_id = 1
        GROUP BY vendor_id, subcategory_id
    ) AS b
    ON a.inserted_at = b.latest_price_time AND a.vendor_id = b.vendor_id AND a.subcategory_id = b.subcategory_id
    WHERE a.category_id = 1
    GROUP BY a.subcategory_id
) AS d
ON c.price = d.min_price AND c.subcategory_id = d.subcategory_id
WHERE c.category_id = 1
```

Before I go any further, I wanted to see if there was an easier way. When it comes to grouping/aggregating results of additional groupings/aggregations, is there a method that will give me the best performance (most important) and/or be easier to read (less important)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a "greatest-n-per-group" query and it's quite complicated to write in MySQL - first due to lack of window functions and second because you have 2 greatest-n-per-group specifications, first for the latest date per vendor and second for the lowest price per subcategory.

Here's one, rather complex way to write this:

```
SELECT 
    ps.subcategory_id,  ps.vendor_id,  ps.price   -- , p.inserted_at
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT subcategory_id
      FROM product
      WHERE category_id = 1
    ) AS s
  JOIN
    product AS ps
      ON  ps.category_id = 1
      AND ps.subcategory_id = s.subcategory_id
      AND ps.id =
          ( SELECT psv.id
            FROM
                ( SELECT DISTINCT subcategory_id, vendor_id
                  FROM product
                  WHERE category_id = 1
                ) AS sv
              JOIN
                product AS psv
                ON  psv.category_id = 1
                AND psv.subcategory_id = sv.subcategory_id
                AND psv.vendor_id = sv.vendor_id
                AND psv.inserted_at =
                    ( SELECT pi.inserted_at
                      FROM product AS pi
                      WHERE pi.category_id = 1
                        AND pi.subcategory_id = sv.subcategory_id
                        AND pi.vendor_id = sv.vendor_id
                      ORDER BY pi.inserted_at DESC
                      LIMIT 1
                    )
            WHERE sv.subcategory_id = s.subcategory_id
            ORDER BY psv.price,
                     psv.vendor_id
            LIMIT 1
          ) ;
```

Tested in [SQLfiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59606/41). Not too bad of a plan either, with a proper index on `(category_id, subcategory_id, vendor_id, inserted_at)`.

It may not be the most efficient and I would definitely experiment with indexes (see the Fiddle, where I have one more index. It may not be very useful but test t on bigger tables.)

(the first version of the query in [SQLfidle-1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59606/41))

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did quite a bit of research on greatest-n-per-group but I couldn't find much on nested versions. As my query got to a few layers deep, I decided to come here in hopes of finding some feature of which I wasn't aware. Turns out I was along the right track, I suppose. Thanks again!

Comment: I edited the query a bit. Both versions should produce the same result.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    d.subcategory_id,
    d.vendor_id,
    MIN(d.price) AS price,
    d.inserted_at
FROM product AS d
JOIN (SELECT
        b.category_id,
        b.subcategory_id,
        b.vendor_id,
        a.last_iat
    FROM product AS b 
    JOIN (SELECT
            a.category_id,
            a.subcategory_id,
            a.vendor_id,
            a.price,
            MAX(a.inserted_at) AS last_iat
        FROM product AS a
        GROUP BY a.category_id,a.subcategory_id,a.vendor_id
        ) AS a
        ON (a.category_id=b.category_id AND a.subcategory_id=b.subcategory_id AND a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id)
    GROUP BY b.category_id,b.subcategory_id,b.vendor_id) AS c
    ON (c.category_id=d.category_id AND c.subcategory_id=d.subcategory_id AND c.last_iat=d.inserted_at)
WHERE d.category_id=1
GROUP BY d.category_id,d.subcategory_id;
```

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->     d.subcategory_id,
    ->     d.vendor_id,
    ->     MIN(d.price) AS price,
    ->     d.inserted_at
    -> FROM product AS d
    -> JOIN (SELECT
    ->         b.category_id,
    ->         b.subcategory_id,
    ->         b.vendor_id,
    ->         a.last_iat
    ->     FROM product AS b 
    ->     JOIN (SELECT
    ->             a.category_id,
    ->             a.subcategory_id,
    ->             a.vendor_id,
    ->             a.price,
    ->             MAX(a.inserted_at) AS last_iat
    ->         FROM product AS a
    ->         GROUP BY a.category_id,a.subcategory_id,a.vendor_id
    ->         ) AS a
    ->         ON (a.category_id=b.category_id AND a.subcategory_id=b.subcategory_id AND a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id)
    ->     GROUP BY b.category_id,b.subcategory_id,b.vendor_id) AS c
    ->     ON (c.category_id=d.category_id AND c.subcategory_id=d.subcategory_id AND c.last_iat=d.inserted_at)
    -> WHERE d.category_id=1
    -> GROUP BY d.category_id,d.subcategory_id;
+----------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
| subcategory_id | vendor_id | price | inserted_at         |
+----------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
|              1 |         2 |  9.00 | 2015-07-26 08:00:00 |
|              2 |         3 | 16.00 | 2015-07-23 04:00:00 |
+----------------+-----------+-------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**Explain:**

*I used the index recommendation from @ypercube.*

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT d.subcategory_id, d.vendor_id, MIN(d.price) AS price, d.inserted_at FROM product AS d JOIN (SELECT b.category_id, b.subcategory_id, b.vendor_id, a.last_iat FROM product AS b  JOIN (SELECT a.category_id, a.subcategory_id, a.vendor_id, a.price, MAX(a.inserted_at) AS last_iat FROM product AS a GROUP BY a.category_id,a.subcategory_id,a.vendor_id ) AS a ON (a.category_id=b.category_id AND a.subcategory_id=b.subcategory_id AND a.vendor_id=b.vendor_id) GROUP BY b.category_id,b.subcategory_id,b.vendor_id) AS c ON (c.category_id=d.category_id AND c.subcategory_id=d.subcategory_id AND c.last_iat=d.inserted_at) WHERE d.category_id=1 GROUP BY d.category_id,d.subcategory_id;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                                        | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL                                       |    4 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | d          | ALL   | q_ix          | NULL | NULL    | NULL                                       |    5 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL                                       |    4 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  2 | DERIVED     | b          | ref   | q_ix          | q_ix | 15      | a.category_id,a.subcategory_id,a.vendor_id |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  3 | DERIVED     | a          | index | NULL          | q_ix | 19      | NULL                                       |    5 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. While yours is actually easier to understand, I chose ypercube's answer as the correct one since his was more "technically" correct. I needed to be able to specify the category ID. I know it would be very easy to modify yours, but I can only choose 1 answer anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the one by @oNare but I think it is not robust because if I change min to max, it outputs the wrong vendor.

My approach is to join two tables, **table_date** and **table_price**. The table_date is grouped by latest dates,  and table_price is based on pricing that has been derived from a table similar to table_date.

```sql
SELECT subcategory_id, MIN(vendor_id) AS vendor_id, price
FROM (
    SELECT  table_date.subcategory_id, table_date.vendor_id, price, table_date.latest_date
    FROM (SELECT b.subcategory_id, a.vendor_id, price, a.latest_date FROM product AS b
        JOIN (SELECT subcategory_id, vendor_id, MAX(inserted_at) AS latest_date
                FROM product AS a
                WHERE category_id=1
                GROUP BY category_id, subcategory_id, vendor_id
                ) AS a
            ON b.subcategory_id=a.subcategory_id AND b.inserted_at=a.latest_date
        WHERE b.category_id=1
        ) AS table_date
    JOIN (SELECT subcategory_id, MIN_price 
            FROM (SELECT b.subcategory_id, a.vendor_id, MIN(price) AS MIN_price, a.latest_date FROM product AS b
            JOIN (SELECT subcategory_id, vendor_id, MAX(inserted_at) AS latest_date
                FROM product AS a
                WHERE category_id=1
                GROUP BY category_id, subcategory_id, vendor_id
                ) AS a
                ON b.subcategory_id=a.subcategory_id AND b.inserted_at=a.latest_date
            WHERE b.category_id=1
            GROUP BY b.subcategory_id
                ) AS c
            ) AS table_price
        ON table_date.subcategory_id = table_price.subcategory_id AND table_date.price = table_price.MIN_price) AS final
GROUP BY subcategory_id;
```